# I am try to purchase product using paypal but product stock not decrease in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am try to purchase product using pay pal but product stock not decrease in wordpress.
Order status display Pending.
How to solve?
Woccomerce v2.1.11
Woccomerce is customized in my theme.

Comment: 2.1 is an old version... don't get stuck on older version... it is prone to errors and possibly some hacks... updates are there for a reason... your problem is one of these errors... and there's a major change coming for version 3. Very big change...

Comment: Yes.i have totaly customized woocommerce in my theme.Thank you.

Comment: if the customization is in the theme, update the plugin... otherwise, try to transfer the changes in your theme so that you can update your plugin...

Comment: Ok.thank you.I am trying to update woocommerce

Comment: Hello, Reigel I have update woocomerce but its still same problem.